# how to define factories with a inheritance user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I got following problem:
In my application i use inheritance to define my user model:

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :name...
 field :bla...
end


class CustomUser < User
 field :customuserfield...
end
```

How can i write factories to map this Class hirachie in my specs.
And keep up writing with don´t repeat yourself.

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
    name  "name"
    bla "bla"

    factory :custom_user do
      customfield "customfield"
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn´t work for me because the class is also "User".
With "User" i got a invalid error because the customfields are not defiend here.
Is there a good practice, way or method to relize something like that.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can try this:

```
factory :user do
  name  "name"
  bla "bla"
end

factory :custom_user, class: CustomUser, parent: :user do
  customfield "customfield"
end
```

For more info: [Inheritance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#inheritance).

Comment: yea it worked with parent... but i need to add class: CustomUser--> (factory :custom_user, class:CustomUser, parent: :user )

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for to my problem.  Wish I could upvote this multiple times.

Answer (score 16):

Just add the class: CustomUser to :custom_user factory. That works for me. When you nested in :user it means parent is User, but it is simpler.

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
    name  "name"
    bla "bla"

    factory :custom_user, class: CustomUser do
      customfield "customfield"
    end
  end
end
```