# Defining a FactoryGirl factory which associates to a model which inherits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, sorcery

Has anyone come across this:

I have something like this:

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    authenticates_with_sorcery!

    attr_accessible :forename, :surname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
...
end

class Manager < User
  has_many :things_to_manage

...
end

class ThingsToManage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :stuff, :more_stuff

  belongs_to :manager

...
end
```

And I want to set up a factory so that FactoryGirl.create(:things_to_manage) will create a ThingsToManager model (persisted in a database) with a Manager (which inherits from User)

My factories are something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        forename 'Test'
        surname 'User'
        sequence(:email) {|n| "#{forename}.#{surname}#{n}@test.com".downcase}
        password 'lalala123@@'
        end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :manager do

  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :things_to_manage do

    stuff "rhubarb rhubarb"
    more_stuff "la la la"
    association :manager, :factory => :user

  end
end
```

The `association :manager, :factory => :user` doesn't work; I get

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Manager(#70275174714940)
>   expected, got User(#70275151319360)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using single table inheritance correctly with a "type" field?

Comment: Hi Beerlington - I'm not sure, it looked right to me... can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344484/265985) you could try changing your manager factory to:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :manager, class: Manager, :parent => :user do

  end
end
```

And then your things_to_manage factory to:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :things_to_manage do

    stuff "rhubarb rhubarb"
    more_stuff "la la la"
    manager

  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for info, but when I do this I get an error (undefined method `password_attribute_name' for nil:NilClass). So I guess the factory is trying to invoke a method on the User model. Maybe there's a way to create a User before the create and have it's id associate with the ThingsToManage model?