# Specifying associations to inherited factory with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've just started using FactoryGirl for my tests, and I've run into some issues.

I have `user`, `qualification` and `user_qualification` models. For `qualifications`, I have two inherited factories, namely `qualification_ba` and `qualification_phd`. Now, I'm trying to generate a qualification that includes either `qualification_ba` or `qualification_phd` factories by running:

`create(:user_qualification_ba_bad_marks)`.

This returns:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'qualification_ba='`.

However, when running:

`create(:qualification_ba)`

it successfully creates the object as expected. Is there perhaps a limit on how deep you can nest factories?

```
factory :user do
    to_create {|instance| instance.save(validate: false) }

    full_name               Faker::Name.name
    email                   Faker::Internet.email
    password                Faker::Internet.password(8)

    factory :user_ba_candidate do
        before(:create) do |user|
                create_list(:user_qualification_ba_bad_marks, 1, user: user)
        end
    end

    factory :user_phd_candidate do
        before(:create) do |user|
                create_list(:user_qualification_phd_good_marks, 1, user: user )
        end
    end

end
factory :qualification do
    user_selectable true
    factory :qualification_ba do
        name                    "Bachelors"
        qualification_level     2
    end
    factory :qualification_phd do
        name                    "Masters"
        qualification_level     5
    end
end

factory :user_qualification do
    to_create {|instance| instance.save(validate: false) }
    factory :user_qualification_ba_bad_marks do
        qualification_ba
        aggregate (30..50).to_a.sample
    end
    factory :user_qualification_phd_good_marks do
        qualification_phd
        aggregate (70..90).to_a.sample
    end
    user
end
```

Comment: you can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343876/how-to-define-factories-with-a-inheritance-user-model