# How to define two new attributes in a factory which is defined inside another factory in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory

I have two models named `Student` and `Teacher`. Both of them have same fields like `name`, `age` etc. Except `Teacher` has two extra attributes `qualification` and `college`. Now for writing rspec, I decided to created factories for the same as below:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :student do
    type 'student'

    factory :teacher do
      type 'teacher'
      qualification BA
      college XYZ
    end
  end
end
```

I defined the `teacher` inside `student` because both of them have same attributes except `teacher` has two extra attributes. I added the attributes as above, but it gave error as:

```
  1) Teacher#default_value_for 
     Failure/Error: it { expect(subject.qualification).to be_false}

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `qualification' for #Student:0x0000000e8c0088'

Finished in 1.75 seconds (files took 14.48 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

How to add those attributes in `Teacher` factory?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try separated factories ?

Comment: Yea i tried that and separating the factories work. But I just want to try out new and better ways for writing specs. That's why I added the factory inside the existing factory. So is there any to do it?

Comment: Your factory specification does not work like this, because it is nested it will still create a `Student`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Student` and `Teacher` models are 2 different classes without inheritance, you can't do what you're trying to achieve.

According to the [FactoryBot source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#inheritance):

> You can easily create multiple factories **for the same class** without
>   repeating common attributes by nesting factories
>
> ```
> factory :post do
>   title { "A title" }
>
>   factory :approved_post do
>     approved { true }
>   end
> end
> ```

You can actually write nested factories if `Teacher` inherits the `Student` class.
Example here: [how to define factories with a inheritance user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343876/how-to-define-factories-with-a-inheritance-user-model)

Comment: `Teacher` and `Student` both are inheriting from `School` model...I tried your solution but it gave the same error. @sovalina. Can I achieve what I want if they are inheriting from same model?

Comment: @Moriarty you can define a `school` factory with 2 nested `student` and `teacher` factories but you can't nest `teacher` inside the `student` one

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue by removing the nesting in the factories.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :student do
    type 'student'
  end

 factory :teacher do
   type 'teacher'
   qualification BA
   college XYZ
 end
end
```

This created two different factories in the same factory. :)